# javascript counter increment by 1 except decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, increment

I have 3 numbers (90, 75.5, 2.5). I use a counter in jquery incrementing by 1 this numbers.
I would like to increment only by 1 and not increment the decimals.
The result must be (90, 75.5, 2.5) and not (90.0, 75.5, 2.5)
Is it possible ?

```js
$(".count").delay(2000).each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 2500,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(now);
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count">90</div>
<div class="count">75.5</div>
<div class="count">2.5</div>
```

Comment: how the result is different from current value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animated counter value will follow whatever easing function you apply to the animation, but you can manipulate the display of that value however you like within the `step` function.

Here I capture the decimal portion of the number before the animation starts; and at each step of the animation round off the counter, then replace the original decimal portion:

```js
$(".count").delay(2000).each(function() {
  // capture the original decimal. 
  // This would be nice, but doesn't work for negative numbers and is prone to floating point errors:
  // var mantissa = Number($(this).text()) - Math.floor($(this).text()); 
  // so instead we'll use icky string manipulation:
  var mantissa = 0;
  var orig = $(this).text();
  if (orig.indexOf('.')>-1) {
    mantissa = orig.substring(orig.indexOf('.'))
  }

  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 2500,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.floor(now) + mantissa);
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count">90</div>
<div class="count">75.5</div>
<div class="count">2.5</div>
<div class="count">-1000.15</div><!-- confirming this works for negative numbers too -->
```

Comment: I want increment only by 1 and not animate the decimals. For the first number I want 90 and 90.0

Comment: I adjusted the answer to round off numbers which have zero after the decimal -- I assume that's what you meant?

Comment: Ah, I see; thanks for updating your comment, that's much more clear.  I've modified the answer again to fit that description.

Comment: Is it possible to increment only by 1 the first number ? I don't want display the decimals for it

Comment: It's not displaying any decimals for the first number.